# What is the difference between the core os projects kube-prometheus and prometheus operator?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator

The github repo of Prometheus Operator https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/ project says that

> The Prometheus Operator makes the Prometheus configuration Kubernetes native and manages and operates Prometheus and Alertmanager clusters. It is a piece of the puzzle regarding full end-to-end monitoring.
>
> kube-prometheus combines the Prometheus Operator with a collection of manifests to help getting started with monitoring Kubernetes itself and applications running on top of it.

Can someone elaborate this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've always had this exact same question/repeatedly bumped into both, but tbh reading the above answer didn't clarify it for me/I needed a short explanation. I found this github issue that just made it crystal clear to me.
https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/2619

Quoting nicgirault of GitHub:

> At last I realized that prometheus-operator chart was packaging
> kube-prometheus stack but it took me around 10 hours playing around to
> realize this.

**Here's my summarized explanation:** 
**"kube-prometheus" and "Prometheus Operator Helm Chart" both do the same thing:**

1. Basically the Ingress/Ingress Controller Concept, applied to Metrics/Prometheus Operator.
2. Both are a means of easily configuring, installing, and managing a huge distributed application (Kubernetes Prometheus Stack) on Kubernetes: 

   **What is the Entire Kube Prometheus Stack you ask?** 
   Prometheus, Grafana, AlertManager, CRDs (Custom Resource Definitions), Prometheus Operator(software bot app), IaC Alert Rules, IaC Grafana Dashboards, IaC ServiceMonitor CRDs (which auto-generate Prometheus Metric Collection Configuration and auto hot import it into Prometheus Server)

   (Also when I say easily configuring I mean 1,000-10,000++ lines of easy for humans to understand config that generates and auto manage 10,000-100,000 lines of machine config + stuff with sensible defaults + monitoring configuration self-service, distributed configuration sharding with an operator/controller to combine config + generate verbose boilerplate machine-readable config from nice human-readable config.

**If they achieve the same end goal, you might ask what's the difference between them?** 
https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus 
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator 
Basically, CoreOS's kube-prometheus deploys the Prometheus Stack using Ksonnet. 
Prometheus Operator Helm Chart wraps kube-prometheus / achieves the same end result but with Helm.

**So which one to use?** 
Doesn't matter + they achieve the same end result + shouldn't be crazy difficult to start with 1 and switch to the other. 
Helm tends to be faster to learn/develop basic mastery of.  
Ksonnet is harder to learn/develop basic mastery of, but:

- it's more idempotent (better for CICD automation) (but it's only a difference of 99% idempotent vs 99.99% idempotent.)
- has built-in templating which means that if you have multiple clusters you need to manage / that you want to always keep consistent with each other. Then you can leverage ksonnet's templating to manage multiple instances of the Kube Prometheus Stack (for multiple envs) using a DRY code base with lots of code reuse. (If you only have a few envs and Prometheus doesn't need to change often it's not completely unreasonable to keep 4 helm values files in sync by hand. I've also seen Jinja2 templating used to template out helm values files, but if you're going to bother with that you may as well just consider ksonnet.)

Answer (score 8):

`Kubernetes operator` are kubernetes specific application(pods) that configure, manage and optimize other Kubernetes deployments automatically. They are implemented as a custom controller.

According to official coreOS website:

> Operators were introduced by CoreOS as a class of software that operates other software, putting operational knowledge collected by humans into software.

The prometheus operator provides the easy way to deploy configure and monitor your prometheus instances on kubernetes cluster. To do so, prometheus operator introduces three types of custom resource definition(CRD) in kubernetes.

1. Prometheus
2. Alertmanager
3. ServiceMonitor

Now, with the help of above CRD's, you can directly create a prometheus instance by providing `kind: Prometheus` and the prometheus instance is ready to serve, likewise you can do for `AlertManager`. Without this you would have to setup the deployment for prometheus with its image, configuration and many more things.

> The Prometheus Operator serves to make running Prometheus on top of Kubernetes as easy as possible, while preserving Kubernetes-native configuration options.

Now, kube-prometheus implemented the prometheus operator and provides you minimum yaml files to create your basic setup of `prometheus`, `alertmanager` and `grafana` by running a single command.

```
git clone https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator.git
kubectl apply -f prometheus-operator/contrib/kube-prometheus/manifests/
```

By running above command in kube-prometheus directory, you will get a `monitoring` namespace which will have an instance of alertmanager, `prometheus` and `grafana` for UI. This is enough setup for most of the basic implementation and if you need any more specifics according to your application, you can add more yamls of exporter you need.

Kube-prometheus is more of a contribution to prometheus-operator project, which implements the prometheus operator functionality very well and provide you a complete monitoring setup for your kubernetes cluster. You can start with kube-prometheus and extend the functionality of your monitoring setup according to your application from there.

You can learn more about prometheus-operator [here](https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/user-guides/getting-started.html)

Comment: We have recently split both projects into their separate repositories again:

https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator
https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus

In the future this should be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, 28-09-2020, this is the way to install Prometheus in a Kubernetes cluster
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack#kube-prometheus-stack

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation, kube-prometheus-stack is a rename of prometheus-operator.
As I understood, kube-prometheus-stack also has preinstalled grafana dashboards and prometheus rules.

> Note: This chart was formerly named prometheus-operator chart, now
> renamed to more clearly reflect that it installs the kube-prometheus
> project stack, within which Prometheus Operator is only one component.

Taken from https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

Answer (score 0):

Architecturally the container runs docker
The default container logs are managed by Docker, and the default log driver uses JSON-file
  `log-driver": "json-file`

`https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/`  
If the default jSON-file is used to manage container logs, log rotation is not performed by default. Therefore, the default JSON-file log driver the log files stored by the log driver can result in a large amount of disk space for containers that generate a large amount of output, which can cause disk space to run out.

In this case, save the log to ES, store it separately, and periodically delete the index using curator kubernetes
And run a scheduled task in K8S to delete the index periodically

Another solution for disk space is to periodically delete old logs from jSON-files
Typically we set the size and number of logs

This will set up a maximum of 10 log files, each with a maximum size of 20 Mb. Therefore, the container has a maximum of 200 Mb of logs
  `"log-driver": "json-file", "log-opts": { "max-size": "20m", "max-file": "10" },`

Note: In general, the default Docker log is placed
  `/var/lib/docker/containers/`  
But in the same case kubernetes also saves logs and creates a directory structure to help you find pods-based logs, so you can find container logs for each Pod running on a node
  `/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod_name>_<pod_id>/<container_name>/`

When removing pod, / var/lib/container under the docker/containers/log and k8s created under/var/log/pods/pod log will be deleted

For example, if the POD is restarted during production, the pod log will be deleted whether it is on the original node or jumped to another node
Therefore, this log needs to be saved in ES for centralized management. Many R&D projects will check the log for troubleshooting in most cases